# How to send file attachment with HTTP request in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, http, aws-lambda

I would like to send a file saved on a local drive as `~/Users/User/Images/photo.jpg`
I would like to send `http` request to the endpoint handle that is defined below. With the http request I would like to send photo.jpg image as a file attachment. What would be a shortest way to do it in Nodejs?

AWS API Gateway Lambda endpoint:

```
exports.handler = async function(httpRequest) {
  console.info(httpRequest);
  
  return 'Hello world'
}
```

Comment: From a Lambda (or from a server) you can't control where users save their files. Browsers prevent this, and it would be a security problem.

Comment: Can you upload to S3 instead? You can still do this with a Lambda (if you have an API gateway) but pushing to S3 and then triggering a Lambda may be best so that you do not pay for extra Lambda run time. That aside, can you please show us some of the front-end JS code you have which sends the file? The question needs more focus.